# RestAPI url for getting all wiki pages in a library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, wiki-pages

I am looking for the url syntax to get all the wiki pages in a SharePoint 2013 wiki library. I have tried numerous syntax's to no avail. for example, to get list items I use:

/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List name')/items

I thought it would be simple but everything I have tried has not worked. for example:

/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('relative url')/Files

doesn't produce an error but doesn't return any of the pages in the library. Also, there are no folders in my wiki library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:
1. `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/LibraryName')/files`. If this is not working for you, check the relative URL is correct. For eg: for a site collection starting with `/sites/siteColl`, relative URL would be `/sites/SiteColl/SitePages`. Also, navigate to the library to check the correct URL.
2. `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LibName')/items` 
3. If both of the above, don't work for you try using, `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LibName`. Load `/_vti_bin/lisdata.svc` to check the proper list name and then call this with the proper name.

Comment: The second option worked for me. I could have sworn that was what I was doing. Thanks!

Comment: I verified option 1 also worked.

Comment: Haha yea, it's weird. Both of the options are the same as described in your question. Not sure where you were going wrong. Anyway, glad it worked :)